# How to easily implement C-like modulo (remainder) operation in python 2.7

Tags: python, c, modulo

Modulo operator `%` on negative numbers is implemented in different way in python and in C. In C:
`-4 % 3 = -1`, while in python:`-4 % 3 = 2`.

I know how to implement python-like modulo in C. I wonder how to do the reverse, that is: easily implement a C-like modulo in python.

Comment: Depending on the C compiler, environment you will get different result for negative modulo.

Comment: Use brackets `- (4 % 3)`

Comment: This is the old div/mod rem/quot debate. TL;DR: Different processors implement this differently thus different languages permit different semantics.

Comment: Yup.  Tabs/spaces V2.0

Comment: @BhargavRao *Use brackets `- (4 % 3)`*  That doesn't apply if the original `-4` and `3` values are variables and not hardcoded constants.  For example:  `int k = i % j`, given `int i = -4` and `int j = 3`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle [Operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) [Precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)  is the culprit. :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao *Operator Precedence is the culprit. :-)*  No.  This has nothing to do with operator precedence.  There is no negation operator in `int k = i % j;` given `int i = -4; int j = 3;`

Comment: There was a discussion going on about this at http://bugs.python.org/issue22477

Answer (score 3):

> easily implement a C-like modulo in python.

Since C does truncation toward zero when integers are divided, the sign of the remainder is always the sign of the first operand. There are several ways to implement that; pick one you like:
`def mod(a, b):  return abs(a)%abs(b)*(1,-1)[a<0]
def mod(a, b):  return abs(a)%abs(b)*(1-2*(a<0))`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the modul to the result if it's negative:

```
int mymod(int a, int b) {
   int res = a % b;
   if (res < 0)
      res += b;
   return res;
}
```

EDIT: and the other way round:

```
def mymod(a, b):
    res = a % b
    if (a < 0):
        res -= b
    return res
```

Comment: `return b;`?  Do you mean `return res;`?

Comment: I think **sygi** was asking for Python code to implement the the behavior of the modulus operator in C.

Comment: Ok, now added the other way, too

Comment: This apparently gives utterly bad results when both a and b are < 0.

Comment: The python mymod() function is incorrect. mymod(-10,10) returns -10, not 0 as it should. The answer from @Armali is correct.